# How to affect multiple properties with ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'd like to affect multiple properties, and also have a command active, on a `UIButton`.

I'm trying to reason about the best way to do this, but could use some input.

Here is what I have:

```
// Listen for changes on the textfields, alter the button UI state
[[RACSignal
  combineLatest:@[ _usernameField.rac_textSignal,_passwordField.rac_textSignal]
  reduce:^id(NSString *username, NSString *password) {
      BOOL valid = [username length] >= 4 && [password length] >= 4;
      _loginButton.enabled = valid;
      _loginButton.alpha = valid ?: 0.65;
      return nil;
  }] subscribeCompleted:^{}];

// Listen for taps
_loginButton.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
    NSLog(@"Tap");
    return [RACSignal empty];
}];
```

This works, but I'd love to hear any recommendations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of thinking about how you can update multiple properties at once, it may be helpful to think of *each* property as a value that changes over time.

Consequently, you can model each property with its own signal (stream of values), reusing a common "base" stream to avoid duplicating the important logic:

```
RACSignal *valid = [RACSignal
    combineLatest:@[ _usernameField.rac_textSignal, _passwordField.rac_textSignal ]
    reduce:^(NSString *username, NSString *password) {
        return @([username length] >= 4 && [password length] >= 4);
    }];

RAC(_loginButton, enabled) = valid;
RAC(_loginButton, alpha) = [valid map:^(NSNumber *b) {
    return @(b.boolValue ? 1 : 0.65);
}];
```

This also has the nice benefit of avoiding any side effects.

Comment: If I have the `RAC(_loginButton, enabled)` set up, how would you also set up a command on that button without re-binding `enabled`? Or do you recommend just using IBActions or normal target/action callbacks on buttons?

Comment: @drhr Instead of binding directly to `enabled`, you can pass the `valid` signal into `-[RACCommand initWithEnabled:signalBlock:]`.

Comment: If I do `_loginButton.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:loginValid signal...` I still get the error about re-binding `enabled`..  Should I not be using `rac_command`?

Comment: `[[_loginButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        NSLog(@"ABC");
    }];`   Seems to do the trick.

Comment: Actually, I guess not because that doesn't let me return a `RACSignal *` from the button press... hmm..

Comment: I am dense.  I removed the `RAC(_loginButton, enabled)`. That solves that.  I'll play around with it now, thanks for helping me sort some of this out!

Answer (score 0):

JFI I use multiple assignments to bind several properties to one signal. Like this. It's pretty to read in my mind.

```
RAC(self.channelLabel, textColor) = 
RAC(self.roomNameTextField, textColor) = [RACObserve(self, roomImage) map:^id(id value) {
    return value ? [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor blackColor];
}];
```